# Is it possible to use dict comprehension in a for loop without creating a new dict?

Tags: python, loops, syntax-error, list-comprehension

In Python 3.5, I am trying to iterate over a `for` loop using `dict` comprehension, yet it does not seem to work as it does with `list`. The following will be reported as a syntax error (not by PyCharm, only at runtime):

```
for k, v in (k, v for k, v in {"invalid": 1, "valid": 2}.items() if k == "valid"):  # syntax error
    print("Valid: " + (str(v)))
```

While the following works:

```
for e in (e for e in ["valid", "invalid"] if e == "valid"):  # works
    print(e)
```

I know creating a new `dict` would work (e.g. ), but I want to avoid the overhead as I am just doing operations on the elements.

```
for k, v in {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if k == "valid"}.items():  # works
    print("Valid: " + (str(k)))
```

Of course, I could use a plain old `if k == "valid": continue` condition inside the loop, but I would like to understand why `dict` comprehension seems to be more limited than with `list`.

Comment: That's a generator expression in your first example, not a dict comprehension. Your last example is the only one that has a dict comprehension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python needs parentheses around the first `k, v`.

```
((k, v) for k, v in {"invalid": 1, "valid": 2}.items() if k == "valid")
```

Otherwise it looks like you're trying to make a tuple with two elements:

1. `k`
2. `v for k, v in ...`

The second isn't syntactically valid. (It would be if you put parentheses around it, making it a generator expression.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a tuple with k, v  i.e `(k,v)`:

```
for k, v in ((k, v) for k, v in {"invalid": 1, "valid": 2}.items() if k == "valid"):  
              ^^^
```

That is what is causing the syntax error. If you did the same thing with a list, set comprehension etc.. it would be exactly the same, you need to use a container if you want to add more that one element. The second example `(e for e...` works because you are returning a single element each time, the first two examples are also  generator expressions only the latter is actually a dict comp.